# How to auto answer the "npm init -y vue"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ubuntu, npm

I want to run "`npm init -y vue`" in bash script, and make everything `auto answer` without any manually input.

I found this link with setting the default values in `npm init` but it is not enough:
https://dev.to/atapas/tips-to-customize-npm-init-to-make-it-your-own-253h

**When running:**

```
# npm init -y vue
```

**The following prompts will ask "`No/Yes`", and manually hit enter to "`No`" by default:**

```
Vue.js - The Progressive JavaScript Framework

✔ Project name: … vue-project
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit Testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? › No
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue DevTools 7 extension for debugging? (experimental) … No / Yes
```

How to auto answer with "`Yes`" in all the above prompts?

Comment: Here is the [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805067/is-there-a-way-to-force-yes-to-any-prompts-when-installing-from-apt-get-from) yes | npm init -y vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yes` command is what you are looking for. It has been designed around writing `y` constantly to STDOUT until terminated. But if you want to accept the default values, without providing an actual value, you can modify the default behaviour. Check the man-page for more information.

For your use-case to simulate "" keystrokes, you can run the following command

```bash
yes "" | npm init -y vue
```

Further information:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html

Answer (score 1):

The yes command repeatedly outputs a string (by default, "y") until it's terminated.

```
yes | npm init -y vue
```

Here is the reference : https://askubuntu.com/questions/805067/is-there-a-way-to-force-yes-to-any-prompts-when-installing-from-apt-get-from